# I want to search for values in a Table created with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, updates

So i have the following code to generate the entire Windows Update History:

$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()

$Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Title, Description, Date,

@{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){

1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}

}}}

My question is how can i search in this table for updates containing KB. So for instance i want to know if the update KB4052623 has been installed. How can i write a simple piece of code to tell me KB4052326 has been found in the output of above code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the array returned by QueryHistory to a variable, then loop through that array to get the objects.  Probably easiest to use Regex to find the KB numbers.

This code just list the found KB numbers, but you should be able test it as needed.  Also, you may want to check the Description for KB numbers as well, it may tell you that it replaces old KB numbers or other important info.

```
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Searcher = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher()

$historyCount = $Searcher.GetTotalHistoryCount()

$MSUpdateHistory = $Searcher.QueryHistory(0, $historyCount) | Select-Object Title, Description, Date,

    @{name="Operation"; expression={switch($_.operation){

        1 {"Installation"}; 2 {"Uninstallation"}; 3 {"Other"}

}}}

$MSUpdateHistory | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_.Title -match '(?<KBNum>KB\d+)') {
        Write-Host "Found $($Matches.KBNum)"
    #$_.Description
    #$_.Date
    #$_.Operation
    }
}
```